# finding first prime number with digit length N

Tags: python

I have to make a program that from random numbers with N digits, which N is given by user, the program must print the first prime number it finds.
However, I have to check if a number is prime using the following and only equation: a^p=a mod p. (a is a random number and takes different values each time).
If p passes the test 10 times, then it's a prime, if it fails even once, it's not.

My problem is that "a^p = a mod p" isn't always working. My pals said that it's right and it should work.

Here's my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import random
found = False
flag = True
def prime(p):
 i=0
 flag = True
 while (i<10) and (flag == True):
  i+=1
  a=random.randint(1,10)
  if a**p!=a%p:
   flag=False
   break
 if flag==True:
  return 1
 else:
  return 0

n = int(raw_input("Enter length: "))
if n==0:
 print "Enter another value except: 0"
while found==False:
 if n!=0:
   x=(10**(n-1))
   y=(10**n - 1)
   num = random.randrange(x, y)
 if prime(num):
  print str(num) + " is a prime number"
  found=True
else:
  print str(num) + " is not a prime number"
```

Comment: I'm guessing it should be `(a**p) % p != a % p`

Comment: Beware of integer overflow: `a ** p` can exceed maxint

Comment: You could also use `pow` with modulo as third argument. `pow(a,p,p) != a % p`

Comment: there is no *maxint* in python!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because of the difference between mathematical notation and the Python equivalent.

You have to use [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to do a probabilistic primality test. The relevant formula is `a^p = a (mod p)`. Note that the `(mod p)` applies to the whole equation and not only to the right side.

Example: 11 = 6 (mod 5) in math (because 11/5 = 2 with **remainder 1**, just as 6/5 = 1 with **remainder 1**), but `11 != 6%5` because `11 != 1`.

You have to do `%p` on both sides of the equation or better yet, use Python's 3 parameter `pow` [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow) that does exactly what you need (copied from [tobias_k's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28025386/finding-first-prime-number-with-digit-length-n/28025762#comment44436307_28025386)).